# Map и регулярные выражения

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, map

Ошибка добавления в map при использовании библиотеки regex, кто подскажет что и с чем это едят? и как исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему в вопросе использована картинка, а не нормальный человеческий текст? И при чем здесь "регулярные выражения"?

Comment: @AnT Просто я не встречал такой проблемы, подключил regex думал в regex проблема) но оказалось что совсем другое, картинка как пример ошибки) спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Совершенно неверно сформулированный неверно вопрос, еще и заданный в виде копии экрана, не дает никакого толку для других посетителей...

Answer (score 1):

Выражение с ошибкой - бессмыслица. У `std::map` есть только один подходящий в этом случае метод `insert` с двумя параметрами - шаблонный `insert`, который принимает на вход диапазон итераторов (два итератора). Вот компилятор и воспринимает ваш вызов, как вызов с двумя итераторами. Но `std::string` не является итератором. Все в результате накрывается при попытке "инкрементировать итератор" внутри реализации `insert` - у класса `std::string` нет поддержки операторов `++` и `*`.

Если у вас `std::map<std::string, std::string>` и вы хотели использовать метод для вставки целого элемента (пары), то это либо

```
types_conflicts.insert({ str4, str3 });
```

либо

```
types_conflicts.emplace(str4, str3);
```